# REST url structure for PUT request

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel, restful-architecture

In my app a user can change his password/name/etc by sending a PUT request to **myapp.dev/user**

When I send the request I have a authorization header for basic auth. So the backend will then find the user by checking the auth header.

But should I change my url to this instead: **myapp.dev/user/user_id**

When I check other API's I see that some include an id and some not, so what is the best practise?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend greatly on how you structure your app. In your case as the user is updating own profile. I strongly recommend dropping the id from the URI.
Also it will save you the effort of identifying own user id, to send the correct endpoint.

Comment: So I should use: myapp.dev/user   ?

Comment: Yes, that's my recommendation

Answer (score 0):

Definitely don't recommend adding the user_id if the context of the user_id is received elsewhere. Just adds extra burden and test cases.

I've seen either no id at all or "me" as a placeholder.